# How to replace RegEx with variable name that RegEx has found?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Let's say I have a variable called `testvar` and string containing this `testvar` too;
I want my function to take that whole string and replace RegEx with that found RegEx.
`/k.*?j/` this RegExp finds all substing that is starting with **k** and ending with **j**.

In my example, it must replace `ktestvarj` with value of it,
and finally, I want to have "some sting characters 123".

```js
var t = 'some sting characters ktestvarj';
var testvar = 123;
var modify = function(str) {
    var teststr = str.replace(/k.*?j/, ' + /k.*?j/ + ');
    console.log(teststr); 
}

modify(t);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `t` be `'some string characters k123j';`?

Comment: I am a bit confused - you want to replace whatever the RegEx matches with what exactly? At one point you say you want to replace it with the match...so from `'some sting characters ktestvarj'` you'd get the same string. But them you say "*I want to have 'some sting characters 123'*", so you want to replace whatever the regex matched with something completely different.

Comment: If I understand, you want to replace words which match your pattern with a variable value.
Why don't you just give the variable in argument ?
```var teststr = str.replace(/k.*?j/, testvar );```

Comment: Inside of k***j it is some string and that string is the name of a variable. So I want to find every substring that contains k in the beginning and j at the end, thake string value between them and replace that k***j with variable(***)

Comment: @FlorianCallewaert Because I don't know how many variables I will have. In my case it is testvar, but maybe it has 50 variables and I don't know any of them

Comment: It would be better to use dictionary `variables` that stores the variables needed for replacement. Otherwise, you need to use `eval('foundVarName')` to make it dynamically.

Comment: @MikeKaskun Yes, that would be nice, but how can I find what is the value between **k** and **j**. You case needs value between these two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have dictionary `variables` that stores variables for replacement. Then you can use replace with custom [function-replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). I've added group capturing `/k(.*?)j/g` - so the first group will be your variable name. And also added global flag to replace every match.

```js
var t = 'some sting characters ktestvarj';

var variables = {
  'testvar': 123,
  'testvar1': 456
};

function replacer(match, p1, offset, string) {
  return variables[p1];
}

var modify = function (str) {
  var teststr = str.replace(/k(.*?)j/g, replacer);
  console.log(teststr); 
}

modify(t);
modify('some ktestvarj sting characters ktestvarj ktestvar1j');
```

Comment: It just returns ktestvarj but that is easy to fix

Comment: Yea, forgot to add global flag :)